# Displaying array inside of another array by checking second arrays value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to display the values inside the array by checking the other arrays value. It's not working. I can't figure this out, can someone help please?

```
var a = [
            [1,[10]],             
            [0,[20]],
            [1,[30]]
        ];

for(i =0, len = a.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (a[i] === 1) {
        console.log(a[i])
    }
};
```

Comment: Please remove all irrelevant tags. This has nothing to do with neither PHP or HTML

Comment: Don't shotgun tags, unless your objective is to be downvoted

Comment: `a[i]` is an array and will never be strictly equal to the integer `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
      for(var k=0;k<a[i].length;k++) {
        if(a[i][k] == 1) {
          console.log(a[i][k]);
        }   
      }
    }
```

i think this is what you're trying to archieve.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't looking deep enough into your data structure to find your '1'. 
your current code is trying to match (for example your first index) `if ([1,[10]] === 1)` which will never evaluate to true. Instead you need to see if your selected index contains what you are looking for

```
const array = [
  [1,[10]],             
  [0,[20]],
  [1,[30]],
];

for (let i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (array[i].includes(1)) {
    console.log(array[1]);
  }
}
```